# Using dssp after chain extraction

Tags: python, pymol

I have a list of PDB IDs with realtive chains IDs that have to be extracted, and then run on `dssp`.
For the single chain extraction I tried several methods, such as:

```
import pymol2
for entry in list:
    with pymol2.PyMOL() as pymol:
        pymol.cmd.fetch(entry)
        pymol.cmd.save(entry + '.cif')
```

Where, for example, if I want to extract chain `AC` for `4YBB`, entry = `4YBBAC`.
This works well in saving the cif files (pymol correctly visualizes them), but makes them not suitable for mkdssp. Indeed, if i run

```
mkdssp 4YBBAC
```

I get

```
DSSP could not be created due to an error:
Is this an mmCIF file?
```

I tried also using Biopython:

```
from Bio.PDB import MMCIFParser
from Bio.PDB.mmcifio import MMCIFIO
parser = MMCIFParser()
io = MMCIFIO()
structure = parser.get_structure("4YBB", "4YBB.cif")
model = structure[0]
chain = model['AC']
io.set_structure(chain)
io.save("4YBBAC.cif")
```

But again, when running mkdssp, I get:

```
DSSP could not be created due to an error:
bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

On a closer inspection, both methods drop the columns `_atom_site.pdbx_formal_charge  _atom_site.auth_comp_id _atom_site.auth_atom_id` from the file, while retaining all the others.
This is the first line of the coordinates from the biopython/pymol file:

```
ATOM   1    N N   . GLY A ? 1   ? -125.713 46.378 -19.108 1.0 77.15  2   AC 1
```

While this is the original file:

```
ATOM   34684  N  N     . GLY C   3  1    ? -125.713 46.378   -19.108  1.00 77.15  ?  2    GLY AC N     1
```

I think that renaming the AC chain to a single-character code would in principle resolve the issue, but it's more of a workaround.

`mkdssp` does support multicharacter chain ids. I've proved it first it by cutting and pasting the chain into the file and then with an ad-hoc parser. I think the issue is with how biopython and pymol extract the chains.

Is this a bug? Am I using the tools incorrectly? Can my purpose be achieved with other (possibly hassle free) methods?

**MORE ON THIS TOPIC ON Biopython GitHub :**

https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/3439

Comment: Could you post the PDBx/mmCIF loop_ before the coordinate lines of the pre and post structures/chains to better show what dropping the column mean

Comment: Biopython 1.81 development https://biopython.org/docs/dev/api/Bio.PDB.DSSP.html has a module for DSSP

Comment: to me looks like https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/MMCIFParser.py is missing 'pdbx_formal_charge' while  https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/mmcifio.py has it.

Comment: If you are you using PyMOL, why not use its [command dss](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Dss)?
PyMOL is annoying for removing most entries bar for ATOM/HETATM data from mmCIF and PDB filenames. So the SS data would not be saved, but it's easy to append to the file (I have done it [here](https://github.com/matteoferla/MichelaNGLo-transpiler/blob/ddedd6cb4dd212d16b129f9cbf3423a7e9a8c39e/michelanglo_transpiler/transpiler_io_mixin.py#L115) for example as NGL.js requires `SHEET` and `HELIX`)

Comment: @saidem why do you think ; "I think that renaming the AC chain to a single-character code would in principle resolve the issue, but it's more of a workaround." , have you tried it ?

Comment: not sure if its relevant didi you checked laast verision of parser ?? https://biopython.org/docs/1.80/api/Bio.PDB.MMCIFParser.html it has : auth_chains - True by default. If true, use the author chain IDs. If false, use the re-assigned mmCIF chain IDs. AND auth_residues - True by default. If true, use the author residue numbering. If false, use the mmCIF “label” residue numbering, which has no insertion codes, and strictly increments residue numbers. NOTE: Non-polymers such as water don’t have a “label” residue number, and will be skipped.